# One page of my responsive site not positioning/scaling properly in Firefox, but fine in Chrome, Opera, and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, responsive-design, fluid-layout

Just started doing some cross-browser testing for my [website](http://willryan.us) and there's some weird things happing with my home page in Firefox.

The slider looks to be smaller than the thumbnails below it, the thumbnails are touching each other, and when you resize your browser, the thumbnails don't scale down (they just overlap more). If you look at the site in Chrome, Safari, or Opera (even chrome/safari on iOS), the slider's width is the same as the thumbnails below, there's space between thumbnails, and everything scales properly when resizing the browser.

I'm also noticing some lagging when I hover over the thumbnail (CSS3 animation), again only when I'm in Firefox.

What gives? What am I doing wrong, or does Firefox get goofy with responsive sites? If it matters, I'm using [this framework](http://responsivegridsystem.com)

EDIT: Also, if you click on any of the thumbnails, it seems like the images on THOSE pages look fine and scale properly. Seems like just the home page is affected.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the frustrating world of web development. Every browser interprets code differently, THAT is the number one challenge of our industry. Even the same browser foundation interprets differently from version to version. Internet Explorer HAS ALWAYS been the worst browser to design for because it is usually 2-3 iterations behind everyone else. AND you HAVE to worry about IE, because it ships with most PCs, it is the most prevalent browser.

So, you have to think about who your audience is, and design on the platform most appropriate for that platform. For example, if your audience is graphic designers, you are safe to develop for modern browsers. But if your audience is the casual, not-to-techie PC user, you have to tailor your designs for IE. (sorry).

You can use a tool like http://browsershots.org/ during development to see how your site is performing in a wide variety of browsers. Or https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#

You then have to learn about the "hacks" to make your site display similar, regardless of the web platform. THAT is an immense subject area and you will have to learn and do research until you understand it.

BUT ALL OF THAT BEING SAID, THE MOST IMPORTANT DESIGN PROBLEM TODAY IS MAKING A RESPONSIVE WEBSITE THAT ADAPTS TO BOTH LARGER AND SMALLER SCREEN SITES.

Mobile is the new black. Going forward you should ALWAYS develop with mobile in mind, unless you KNOW that your audience is NOT the mobile-type, and that is the exception, rather than the rule.

Comment: Ugh... yeah I'm slowly realizing that. This project came about because I wanted to make a responsive version of my website to cater towards the ever-growing mobile userbase. And I've been testing on my iphone/ipad/ios simulator since I started coding. But why the hell is Firefox giving me such a hard time?!

Comment: I definitely agree with this sentiment. In the early days of responsive design, designers used the "graceful degredation" approach, which is to say, design for desktop first and then work your way down. These days, with mobile browsers dominating, a much better approach to responsive design is "progressive enhancement" or starting with the least common denominator and working your way up.

Wish I had a direct response to your question, but I'm not seeing any glaring issues with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Added max-width="100%" height="auto" width="100%" into my img tags for the thumbnails and it seems to be working